# Move table from last index to first

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to move the last row in a table to the first row. I am moving the asp:Wizard's next navigation table row to the top.

Here's my code. What am I doing wrong? The table has 8 rows. It's just a plain jane wizard right now.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var wizard = $("#Wizard1");

        var k = $("#Wizard1 tbody tr td:first-child");
        var m = $("#Wizard1 tbody tr td:first-child").children(":eq(8)");

        var n = m.clone();

        m.remove();
        k.before(n);

    });
```

What I did in the end, which I should have thought about, was i removed the rows and re-added the order. My syntax was a little off in the ? though after re-examine the tree. I apologize for the confusion, but the IE dev toolbar was placing the tree wrong in the inspector for some reason.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var k = $("#Wizard1 tr:first-child td:last-child table tr:first-child");
        var n = k.clone();

        k.remove();
        $("#Wizard1 tr:first-child td:last-child table").append(n);

    });
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?  Like why are selecting all the way down to the `td` and its children?  Don't you want to select `tr`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wizard = $("#Wizard1");

    var k = $("#Wizard1 tbody tr:first-child");
    var m = $("#Wizard1 tbody tr:last-child");
    var n = m.clone();

    m.remove();
    k.before(n);

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
var wizard = document.getElementById("Wizard1");
var rows = wizard.getElementsByTagName("TR");
var firstRow = rows[0];
var lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1];
var rowParent = lastRow.parentNode; // You need the parent to manipulate the rows. Does not matter if it is tbody or the table element

rowParent.replaceChild(lastRow, firstRow);
rowParent.appendChild(firstRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out the first and the last ,and then move their Position.

```
var firstRow = $('#Wizard1').find('tr').eq(0)
var lastRow =  $('#Wizard1').find('tr').eq($('#Wizard1').find('tr').length)

$('#Wizard1').prepend(lastRow);
$('#Wizard1').prepend(firstRow);
```